# Separar informações de identificadores em variaveis (PHP)

Tags: php

Ex: texto texto text id:123456 text text id:124214 text text
Preciso separar os valores do identificar id em variáveis como posso fazer isso em PHP?

Comment: Você quer pegar somente os números? Pode dar um exemplo da saída esperada

Comment: quero somente os números, por que vou substituir na string o id: por um link utilizando o numero como parametro para o link, em vez de id:123456 vai ser <a href="url/123456">123456</a>

Answer (score 2):

Utilize uma expressão regular para combinar apenas os números, a função adequada para isso é [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
$str = 'texto texto text id:123456 text text id:124214 text text';
$er = '/\d+/';
preg_match_all($er, $str, $ocorrencias);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ocorrencias);
```

`\d+` significa combinar/casar apenas números pelo menos uma vez.

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => 124214
        )

)
```

[phpfiddle - exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2b0u-dp7x)

Comment: Mais aonde que utilizado o identificador nessa função no caso o ID:

Comment: @Rdallagnol Não so números que precisava? o que faltou?

Comment: por exemplo na string vai vir com um identificador antes e pode ter varias identificadores por exemplo  id:,ch:, bc:  (text text bc:1111, text text id:4444)

Comment: Sempre tem que pegar dois caracteres os dois pontos e o número. ex: `[a-z]:([0-9]+)`, troque o valor de `$er` por `$er = '/([a-z]+:)(\d+)/';` veja se é isso que você espera, @Rdallagnol

Comment: @rray eu colocaria o "id:" no regex, algo como $er = '/id\:\d+/';

Answer (score 0):

Este método abaixo faz o *parse* na string quebrando ela em *array* usando o explode [explode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) depois busca quais os elementos que possuem a string que você procura usando o [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) e pro fim insere em um *array* apenas os valores que você precisa.

```
$string = "texto texto text id:123456 text text id:124214 text text";
$parser = explode(" ", $string);

foreach($parser as $data){
    if(strpos($data, "id:") !== false) {
        $dataId = explode("id:", $data);
        $ids[] = $dataId[1];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ids);
```

O retorno para usso será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 124214
)
```

Comment: Essa função não funcionou Erlon

Comment: Qual foi o erro?

Comment: Ele não retornou nada dentro dos array, vou colcar o resultado Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => )

Comment: Esse código exatamente não funcionou ou o mlocal onde você aplicou não teve resultado?

Comment: eu simplesmente copiei e colei esse código e mostrou o resultado que postei anteriormente

Comment: falha minha esqueci de fazer a negação do idêntico.Editei

Answer (score 0):

Galera com a ajuda de vocês

```
 $parser = explode(" ", $atualizacao);

     /**** CH ******************/
     foreach ($parser as $data) {
         if (strpos($data, "ch#") !== false) {
             $dataId = explode("ch#", $data);
             $ids[] = $dataId[1];
         }
     }
     //var_dump($ids);
     foreach ($ids as $i => $ch) {
        preg_replace("/\D/", "", $ch);
        $atualizacao = str_replace('ch#' . $ch, '<a href="LINK/' . > $ch . '">' . $ch . '</a>', $atualizacao);
     }
```

agora a unica coisa que falta é remover as letras ou outros caracteres que não são numero